# RabbitMQ, как построить систему?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi

Сейчас есть монолит, в котором в Quartz.NET крутятся задачи, которые хотелось бы вынести в отдельные микросервисы.
Например возьмем сущность `MeteringDevice` (какой-то прибор измерения). Для него в отдельной базе для Quartz'a есть таблица (`import_md`): id (int), request_id (int null), md_id (int), result (varchar null), is_error (bit). В данный момент работает импортирование так, что 1 задача в Quartz лезет в эту таблицу, берет от туда 100 записей в порядке очереди и импортирует приборы, но приборов в моменты времени может быть очень много и 1 задача попросту начинает делать это всё очень долго.
Хотелось бы как-то разбить это на микросервисы, чтобы в случае пиковых нагрузок можно было поднять еще 3-4 этих микросервиса и разделить нагрузку импорта сразу в несколько машин.
Как это лучше сделать? Т.к. запросы на импорт могут быть вызваны не только с Gateway API, но и из самой базы (отдельной Quartz задачей).
Есть ли смысл сделать так: `main gateway api` -> `database`. `metering device producer` (в нем и будут задачи на хождение в базу) -> `rabbitmq` -> -> `services`?
То есть, `metering device producer` забрал из таблицы `import_md` 100 записей, отправил их в RabbitMQ, а уже сами микросервисы будут делать всю дальнейшую работу (импортировать, обновлять запись в базе (проставить `result`, `is_error`)).
И как быть с перезапуском сервисов? Дубликаты запросов на импорт нельзя делать, значит нужно, если запрос на сервисе ушел, то запись про это в базе появилась точно.
В данный момент всё работает так: `server` + `quartz` -> `db` -> внутренняя программа (proxy) -> `remote api`, `remote api` отдает `id` запроса, который складываем в БД, чтобы потом другая задача в Quartz сходила и сделала запрос ответа по ранее выданному `id`.
Так же еще важный момент, что для импорта данных нужно сначала сделать экспорт с api.
Как вижу схему:
[image: export image]

Соответственно потом импорт будет точно так же делать, сначала Quartz заберет 100 записей, кинет их в Rabbit, их обработают микросервисы и положат результат в базу сами.
Возможно, что в такой схеме `Metering Device service` лишний (в этой схеме он и producer, и consumer(!)) и сам gateway api может писать в базу, но как раз и хотелось убрать эту задержку при работе с базой, чтобы ответ от API был минимальный.
Вариант 2: в этой схеме избавиться от Quartz, чтобы в базу писались данные, а потом сразу уходил пуш в rabbit.

Comment: Как так получилось что сырые данные попали в БД? Они изначально должны были писаться в какойнибудь брокер сообщений, а уже от туда потребители должны брать их на обрботку. Для таких сценариев рекомендую использовать kafka или ydb

Comment: Там формируются документы в хранимых процедурах, а делать их сразу же - накладно, проще в момент нужды их создавать, поэтому они "сырые".

Comment: по вашему описанию похоже на outbox pattern (https://habr.com/ru/companies/lamoda/articles/678932/). Рекомендую для вашего сценария kafka вместо rabbitmq по причине что последний больше для операций с быстрым откликом типа запрос-ответ, а kafka она как раз про операционную обработку. Обязательно обратите внимание на то что вы можете получить одно и тоже сообщение более одного раза, поэтому проектируйте идемпотентную обработку

Comment: Kafka будет излишней. Нет задачи делать 1млн RPS, главное, чтобы Gateway API не писало в базу, а кидала это просто в RMQ

Comment: Я сам не имел опыта продуктового использования rabbitmq  поэтому ничего про него сказать не могу, но везде гдя я работал никто его не использовал, даже в тех сценариях для которых он больше подходит чем таже kafka.

Comment: @Nikolay не знаю чем вам так заяц не угодил. Например, [Relativity](https://help.relativity.com/Server2022/Content/System_Guides/Service_bus/Relativity_service_bus/Relativity_service_bus.htm) очень успешно его использует, и брокер там для агентов с довольно длительными операциями.

Answer (score 0):

тут у вас больше про непонимание Quartz и его работы чем про RabbitMQ. Quartz - планировщик, базу он использует для контроля состояния между циклами запуска и все.
Очереди сообщений для вашей задачи точно не нужны, нужно организовать параллельную обработку по статусу:

> задача в Quartz лезет в эту таблицу, берет от туда 100 записей в порядке очереди и импортирует приборы

Тут у вас происходит блокировка и очевидный затык. Чтобы его не происходило, в этой задаче необходимо либо запускать несколько асинхронных задач, реализующих импорт, либо ставить статус 'ГОТОВ_К_ОБРАБОТКЕ' у записи с приборами, по которому делать вычитку и импорт уже из ваших микросервисов.

Напишите в личку - расскажу подробнее как это реализовать.

Comment: Вопрос в первую очередь про Rabbit, с Quartz работаю уже не первый раз. Quartz тут для примера